# Accessing bitcoin wallet

Tags: fraud

Urgent help needed.  Is there any scenario in which the owner of a bitcoin wallet is asked to provide the app owner with monetary backup to access a wallet they are locked out of?

The password was forgotten and the account is now locked after several failed attempts to get in. I'm being told the only way to get in is to provide financial assurance - a percentage of the account balance to access the account.  I don't know the app being used and it sounds very fishy to me but need to ask to be sure